# Is it possible to send more than one image in MMS?

Tags: java, android, send, mms

Is it possible to attach more than one image in android? I use this code :

`intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/file.gif")));`

but I want to send two or three images.

I solved it.
before i have this code :
`Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);`

and now i have this :
`Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);`

and this

`ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();`

`uris.add(Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/file1.gif")));`

`uris.add(Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/file1.gif")));`

`sendIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);`

thank for all

Comment: have you tried to use putExtra() for each image? intent.putExtra(img1) intent.putExtra(img2)

Comment: yes i tried it, but in MMS was only one image